# Exercise in Lee: Proving $\mathbb{S}^2$ is an embedded submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

**Exercise**: Show that spherical coordinates form a slice chart for $\mathbb{S}^2$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ on any open subset where they are defined.

**Solution**: For this post I will just show this for one portion of the sphere, for brevity. $(U, \psi)$ is a spherical coordinate chart on $\mathbb{R}^3$ where $U = (0, \infty) \times (0, \pi) \times (-\pi, \pi)$ and $\psi(\rho, \varphi, \theta) = (\rho\cos\theta \sin\psi, \rho\sin\theta\sin\varphi, \rho\cos\varphi)$.

We know that $\mathbb{S}^2 \cap U$ is just the portion of the sphere where $y > 0$ (in Cartesian coordinates). So, $\psi(\mathbb{S}^2 \cap U) = \{(\cos\theta\sin\varphi, \sin\theta\sin\varphi, \cos\varphi): -\pi < \theta < \pi, 0 < \varphi < \pi\}$. This isn't a $2$-slice of $\psi(U)$ because none of the coordinates are constant. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you wrote down is $\psi(U) \cap \mathbb S^2$, not $\psi(U\cap \mathbb S^2)$. The spherical coordinate map is $\psi^{-1}$, not $\psi$.

Comment: But doesn't the co-domain of a coordinate map have to be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ where $\mathbb{R}^n$ has Cartesian coordinates? $\psi^{-1}$ has as its co-domain $\mathbb{R}^n$ with spherical coordinates.

Comment: In this case, both the domain and the codomain have to be open subsets of $\mathbb R^3$. But you need a map $F$ with the property that $F(\mathbb S^2\cap U)$ is a coordinate slice. That is satisfied by $\psi^{-1}$, not by $\psi$.

Comment: Sorry for such a late reply, the last few days have been hectic. Would it be correct to say that the codomain of a coordinate map must be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the standard smooth structure (the smooth structure determined by the chart $(\mathbb{R}^n, Id)$), and since spherical coordinate charts belong to the standard smooth structure then $\psi^{-1}$ is a coordinate map even though its codomain does not have Cartesian coordinates?

Comment: @ConfusedMonkey: I don't know what you mean by "its codomain does not have Cartesian coordinates." The codomain $U$ of $\psi^{-1}$ is an open subset of $\mathbb R^3$, which we always (unless otherwise specified) consider as a smooth manifold with its standard coordinates. The fact that we're calling the coordinate functions $(\rho,\phi,\theta)$ in this case instead of $(x,y,z)$ does not change the fact that they are the standard coordinates of $\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: I must be very confused. When you wrote the coordinate functions as $(x, y, z)$ then these are indeed standard coordinates - the first component describes the horizontal distance of the point, etc. But when we write $(\rho, \phi, \theta)$, then the first component gives the radial distance, the second component is the azimuthal angle, and so on. So the coordinates $(\rho, \phi, \theta)$ are not the same as the coordinates $(x,y,z)$, so how are $(\rho, \phi, \theta)$ standard coordinates? I thought standard coordinates were Cartesian rectangular coordinates.

Comment: @ConfusedMonkey: But in the set $U = (0, \infty) \times (0, \pi) \times (-\pi, \pi)\subseteq\mathbb R^3$ where $\psi^{-1}$ takes its values, $\rho$ is just the first component, $\phi$ is the second component, and $\theta$ is the third component. These are Cartesian coordinates on that set!

Comment: Let's use an example. Consider the point $(1,0,0)$ in rectangular coordinates. In spherical coordinates, this point is $(1,\pi/2,0)$. So how is $(1, \pi/2, 0)$ a point in Cartesian coordinates? I must be mistaken in my understanding of "Cartesian coordinates".

What you are saying is that in "Cartesian coordinates", the first component doesn't have to describe the horizontal distance, the second point doesn't have to describe the vertical distance, etc? What exactly are Cartesian coordinates then?!

Comment: @ConfusedMonkey: $\psi^{-1}(1,0,0) = (1,\pi/2,0)$, which is just an element of $\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: Thank you, Professor Lee. I have successfully un-confused myself. :)